# Problems instantiating a Julia environment during a Dockerfile build process

Tags: docker, dockerfile, julia

All,

I'm using Julia in a Docker container designed for development. Various developers use the same Dockerfile on a variety of host machines w/ different architectures. Julia is installed in the Docker image but the git repos holding the source are mounted volumes at run-time. It's working just fine except that every time the container is launched we have the hit for reinstantiating the Julia environment. So, I'm trying to bake the instantiated environment into the Docker image at build time.

After installing Julia into the Docker image I then temporarily COPY the project repos to a directory within the the image that is identical to where they will be mounted during run-time. Here is a snippet of the Dockerfile,

```
# syntax = edrevo/dockerfile-plus

ARG PROGRAM_NAME=wrong_program
ARG DOCKER_UBUNTU_VERSION=wrong_version
FROM ubuntu:${DOCKER_UBUNTU_VERSION}
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends \
    libglvnd0 \
    libgl1 \
    libglx0 \
    libegl1 \
    libxext6 \
    libx11-6 \
    glmark2 \
    mesa-utils \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Env vars for the nvidia-container-runtime.
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES graphics,utility,compute

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    apt-utils \
    autotools-dev \
    build-essential \ 
    ca-certificates \
    g++ \
    git \
    iputils-ping \
    libssl-dev \
    nano \
    openssl \
    python-dev \
    unzip \
    vim \
    sed \
    x11-apps 

RUN update-ca-certificates

# Change to non-root privilege
# https://dev.to/emmanuelnk/using-sudo-without-password-prompt-as-non-root-docker-user-52bg
ARG USERNAME=wrongUser
ARG USERID=1000
ARG GID=101
ARG GROUPNAME=dev

RUN addgroup --gid ${GID} ${GROUPNAME}  \
    && adduser --uid ${USERID} --disabled-password --home /home/${USERNAME} --shell /bin/bash --gecos '' ${USERNAME} \
    && adduser  ${USERNAME} sudo \
    && adduser  ${USERNAME} dev  \
    && grep -qxF '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' /etc/sudoers || echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers 

USER ${USERNAME}
RUN grep -qxF 'export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:ow=1;34:tw=1;34:"' ~/.bashrc || echo 'export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:ow=1;34:tw=1;34:"' >> ~/.bashrc

ARG TEMPDIR=${THIRDPARTYDIR}/temp 
RUN echo "THIRDPARTYDIR = ${THIRDPARTYDIR}" && \
    echo "TEMPDIR = ${TEMPDIR}"

#--------------------------------------
#  Install julia
#--------------------------------------
ARG JULIA_VERSION
ARG JULIA_DOWNLOAD_FILE
RUN echo "JULIA_VERSION = ${JULIA_VERSION}" && \
    echo "JULIA_DOWNLOAD_FILE = ${JULIA_DOWNLOAD_FILE}"

COPY --chown=${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} downloads/${JULIA_DOWNLOAD_FILE} ${THIRDPARTYDIR}/
RUN chown ${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} ${THIRDPARTYDIR}/${JULIA_DOWNLOAD_FILE} && \
    chmod 744 ${THIRDPARTYDIR}/${JULIA_DOWNLOAD_FILE} 
WORKDIR ${THIRDPARTYDIR}
RUN tar xf ${JULIA_DOWNLOAD_FILE} && \
    rm -rf ${JULIA_DOWNLOAD_FILE}

WORKDIR ${THIRDPARTYDIR}
RUN sudo ln -s ${THIRDPARTYDIR}/julia-${JULIA_VERSION}/bin/julia /usr/bin/julia && \ 
    sudo apt-get install -y wget
ENV CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${THIRDPARTYDIR}/julia-${JULIA_VERSION}:${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}

# instantiate all Julia Packages
RUN echo "intiantiating Julia Packages"
ARG WORKSPACEDIR
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKSPACEDIR}/src/
COPY --chown=${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} JuliaProjectManifests/ ${WORKSPACEDIR}/src/

RUN echo "WORKSPACEDIR = ${WORKSPACEDIR}" 

#RUN sudo chown -R ${USERNAME}:${GROUPNAME} /tmp
WORKDIR ${WORKSPACEDIR}/src/
COPY --chown=${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} ./julia_instantiate.sh ${WORKSPACEDIR}/src/
RUN chmod +x ./julia_instantiate.sh 
RUN source ./julia_instantiate.sh 
#RUN sudo -E -s \
#   && source ./julia_instantiate.sh \
#   && exit

WORKDIR ${THIRDPARTYDIR}
RUN rm -rf temp
RUN sudo ldconfig

WORKDIR ${THIRDPARTYDIR}/..

CMD ["bash"]
```

To help clarify more... the ARG environment variables are defined on the command line when kicking off the build. That script looks like:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build                                                            \
    --no-cache=false                                                          \
    --network=host   \
    --rm                                                                \
    --build-arg PROGRAM_NAME=${PROGRAM_NAME}                                    \
    --build-arg WORKSPACEDIR=${WORKSPACEDIR}                                    \
    --build-arg USERNAME=${USER}                                    \
    --build-arg USERID=${UID}                                    \
    --build-arg THIRDPARTYDIR=${THIRDPARTYDIR}                                    \
    --build-arg DOCKER_UBUNTU_VERSION=${DOCKER_UBUNTU_VERSION}                                    \
    --build-arg JULIA_VERSION=${JULIA_VERSION}                    \
    --build-arg JULIA_DOWNLOAD_FILE=${JULIA_DOWNLOAD_FILE}            \
    -f ${CDDS}/${DOCKER_BUILD_FOLDER}/${DOCKER_FILE_NAME} \
    -t ${DOCKER_IMAGE} \
    ${DOCKER_BUILD_CONTEXT} \
    2>&1 | tee ${CDDS}/${DOCKER_BUILD_FOLDER}/${DOCKER_BUILD_LOG}
```

When I try to instantiate the project during the docker build I get the following error,

```
#115 sha256:0c589043bbee81f6e25ae6da0177acfea129c478ba518ca117a39838dc68d6f1
#115 0.148 iKinQP/
#115 0.924  Installing known registries into `~/.julia`
#115 1.032 ERROR: SystemError: mktemp: No such file or directory
#115 1.703 Stacktrace:
#115 1.935  [1] systemerror(::Symbol, ::Int32; extrainfo::Nothing) at ./error.jl:168
#115 2.272  [2] #systemerror#48 at ./error.jl:167 [inlined]
#115 2.279  [3] systemerror at ./error.jl:167 [inlined]
#115 2.279  [4] #mktemp#18 at ./file.jl:589 [inlined]
#115 2.279  [5] mktemp at ./file.jl:587 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
#115 2.298  [6] probe_platform_engines!(; verbose::Bool) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/PlatformEngines.jl:280
#115 2.299  [7] probe_platform_engines! at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/PlatformEngines.jl:181 [inlined]
#115 2.299  [8] pkg_server_registry_urls() at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Types.jl:944
#115 2.349  [9] clone_default_registries(::Pkg.Types.Context; only_if_empty::Bool) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Types.jl:868
#115 2.350  [10] clone_default_registries at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Types.jl:862 [inlined]
#115 2.350  [11] find_registered!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Types.jl:1239
#115 2.355  [12] find_registered! at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Types.jl:1200 [inlined]
#115 2.355  [13] check_registered(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1054
#115 2.356  [14] instantiate(::Pkg.Types.Context; manifest::Nothing, update_registry::Bool, verbose::Bool, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Linux, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:833
#115 2.403  [15] instantiate(::Pkg.Types.Context) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:795
#115 2.404  [16] #instantiate#169 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:791 [inlined]
#115 2.404  [17] instantiate() at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:791
#115 2.404  [18] top-level scope at none:1
#115 DONE 2.5s
```

Here is *julia_instantiate.sh* being RUN by the Dockerfile,

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ${WORKSPACEDIR}/src/;
folders=$(ls -d */) 
echo ${folders} 
for m in ${folders[@]}; do
        cd "${WORKSPACEDIR}/src/${m}"
        echo "instantiating: ${WORKSPACEDIR}/src/${m}"
        julia --project=. -e "using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate(); using $(echo "${m}" | tr -d /); exit();"
done
```

- Docker image OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Host OS: WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04
- Docker version: 20.10.6, build 370c289
- Julia version: 1.5.3

Julia issue [#33593](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/33593) seems related but it doesn't give me a work around.

Thoughts on how to work around this?

EDIT:
Another point is that if I COPY *julia_instantiate.sh* into the docker image but don't execute it during the build, I get an image with the script and the Julia package source files in the image. If I run this container interactively and manually run *julia_instantiate.sh* it runs just fine. I run the container and attach as the same user that is baked into the docker image. So, it seams that the process fails only when the script is run by docker build.

NOTE: I've updated *julia_instantiate.sh to the minimal that I've been testing with. I've also added some additional information about the Dockerfile.

Comment: What is the base dockerfile? 
Are you using official julia docker image or are you installing julia by yourself in dockerfile?
Julia should automatically create ~/.julia directory if it's not present. 
If the directory is already there, probably this is a problem with privileges. How does the whole dockerfile look like? 
Are you using root, or other user?

Comment: The base is Ubuntu 18.04. I'm installing julia manually. Ignore the creation of ~/.julia (I had put that in during debugging). Since posting I've removed it and the folder gets created just fine. I am NOT root when trying to instantiate. Previously in the Dockerfile I've created a user and switched to that user when installing everything. As I mentioned, I've used this Docker image for months and all the applications work just fine. It's only the most recent step of trying to instantiate my Julia environment during the docker build that is failing.

Comment: Just to be sure, is the ~ home directory of that user and not root?
Is julia installed under that user?
And does that user have rights to write to /tmp?
If you do `sudo`, does instantiation work?

If you use root user, does it work?

Thanks for posting whole dockerfile, I'll try to take a look at it next week if it won't be solved until that time.

Comment: @Matej, thanks for the help. Yes, ~ is to the home directory of the user, not root. Julia is installed under the user, not root.  I added ```RUN sudo chown -R ${USERNAME}:${GROUPNAME} /tmp``` before ```RUN source ./julia_instantiate.sh``` when running as $USERNAME and it did not make a difference. I then removed that command and used the following instead, ```RUN sudo -E -s && source ./julia_instantiate.sh && exit ```
Same error... So, even by running the script as root with the all ENV accessible did not change things. 
BTW: this is not the whole Dockerfile but the most relevant parts...

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer but its only partial, as I am in the midst of learning how to do the same thing. I'm having trouble understanding the dockerfile given, I think the approach might be complicating things and making it hard to find errors.

Here is the approach (not compeletely documented) that has led to me getting a running julia image with packages installed and instantiated.

1. Build from a base image and install julia

- based on the [julia dockerfile at dockerhub](https://github.com/docker-library/julia/blob/master/1.6/buster/Dockerfile)
- this makes a nice starting point for other julia workers based on various package combinations.
- I'm required to build from AL2 base instead of the usual public julia dockerfiles, thats the only reason to do this step separately.

2. FROM this julia base image, run the Pkg.add for various packages, after which run instantiate

- based on this [discourse thread and links within](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/building-a-dockerfile-with-packages/37272)

```
# the important parts of dockerfile
RUN julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add("Pipe", preserve=PRESERVE_DIRECT);'
RUN julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add("DataFrames", preserve=PRESERVE_DIRECT);'
RUN julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add("CSV", preserve=PRESERVE_DIRECT);'

RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir "$JULIA_USER_HOME";

RUN julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate();'
```

[This post from bkamins@, "My practices for managing project dependencies in Julia"](https://www.juliabloggers.com/my-practices-for-managing-project-dependencies-in-julia/) helped a lot, particularly the dependency preservation commands available in Pkg.add.

Sorry this is not a complete solution, I haven't completed the process yet myself but these are things I wish I had found on SO when I started.